# XPC for Long Running Service

Tags: swift, macos, ipc, launchd, xpc

I'm writing a client-server application for OS X. The service needs to run forever, or at least as close as possible. :-)

In the past I have used "classic" Distributed Objects quite successfully with an Objective-C application, but this time I wanted to use Swift and the new shiny IPC technology, XPC!

So, here's my question:

When I create an XPC Mach Service (it needs root privileges) and start it via launchd, the process appears to restart for every new, incoming connection. I have written services started via launchd before and never had this problem. Is there something specific to using XPC that causes this?

My preference is to use a high-level IPC mechanism instead of something more fundamental like Unix domain sockets, but I'm happy to drop down to that level if necessary.

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this one - whether XPC is even supported for this single-instance-service, multiple-client case. I'm working in C/C++/Objective-C rather than Swift.